# How to remove duplicate users with firstname/lastname swapped in sql server

Tags: sql, duplicates

Consider I have a table like the one below :

```
Firstname : LastName
Ajay      : Sharma
Sharma    : Ajay
Gopi      : Nair
Nair      : Gopi
Vikram    : Roy
Anil      : Patel
Patel     : Anil
```

[image]

I would like to get the output as

```
Firstname : LastName

Ajay      : Sharma
Gopi      : Nair
Vikram    : Roy
Anil      : Patel
```

[image]

Comment: wich db you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a list of usual first names and/or last names, it is not possible to keep the one that "looks" like the first name.  So, you have to resort to just keeping one of the pair.

I would go for:

```
select t.firstname, t.lastname
from t
where t.firstname <= t.lastname
union all
select t.lastname, t.firstname
from t
where t.firstname > t.lastname and
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.firstname = t.lastname and
                        t2.lastname = t.firstname
                 );
```

This keeps all rows where `firstname` is less than or equal to `lastname`.  It then keeps inverted pairs where the inversion does not exist.

If you actually want to delete the rows:

```
delete from t
    where t.lastname > t.firstname and
          exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.firstname = t.lastname and
                        t2.lastname = t.firstname
                 );
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, Thanks for the delete row query,It works!!Can you please explain your query?

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME FROM TABLE WHERE 
  LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME NOT IN (SELECT 
  FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME FROM TABLE) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a delete in join with the subquery that in UNION all return the duplicated

```
delete m 
from my_table m
inner 
     (select t.firtname, t.lastname
      from 
          (select firtname, lastname
           from my_table 

           union all

           select lastname, firstname 
           from my_table) t 
      group by 
          t.firtname, t.lastname
      having 
          count(*) > 1) t2 on t2.lastname = m.firstname 
                           and t2.firstname = m.lastname
```

Comment: I dont think this should be rather made complex like this